# Android deep linking open my app

Tags: url, deep-linking

Android when i click on referral link then if my app available then open with referral token else redirect play store and if download from the  play store then also open app with referral token...So how can do??  And Also not asking dialog  open with  directly open my app

```
 <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"  />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/demo/public/1234" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: Please clarify your question explaining better what you have and what you want

Comment: i want user click on URL then redirect my app if already  installed else redirect play store now open my app but asking dialog open with but i dont want that i want directly open app